# How can I retrieve the session data from endpoint when data is sent from stripe's server?

Tags: node.js, next.js, windows-10, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm using next-iron-session for session storage and I need to use Cors at same time, in my endpoint. I export the model's default handler function like this:

```
const withSessionRoute = (handler: (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => Promise<void>) => {
  return withIronSessionApiRoute(cors(handler), ironOptions);
}

export default withSessionRoute(handler);
```

So I retrieve data from the session like this:

```
const handler = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) => {
  
  console.log('req.session = ', req.session);
  // ...
}
```

But when the POST data cames from stripe server the session isn't available. How can I get the session? it isn't available even from a fetch call ta a page that return the session:

```
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/baa');
    const result = await response.json();
    console.log('result = ', result);
```

returns `{id: -1}`

the `baa` page goes like this:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { withIronSessionApiRoute, withIronSessionSsr  } from "iron-session/next";
import CustomSession from '@/interfaces/CustomSession';
import IUser from '@/interfaces/IUser';
import { withSessionRoute } from "@lib/withSession";

const handler = async (
    req: NextApiRequest,
    res: NextApiResponse
  ) => {
  
    const user:IUser = (req.session as CustomSession)?.user || {id: -1};
    res.status(200).json(user);
}

export default withSessionRoute(handler);
```

`withSessionRoute` goes like this:

```
const withSessionRoute = (handler: NextApiHandler) => {
    return withIronSessionApiRoute(handler, ironOptions);
}
```

How can I fix that and get the session data from the endpoint when the post data is sent from stripe server?